# Scaling multiple objects at the same time using ScaleTransform and DoubleAnimation in XAML

Tags: xaml, microsoft-metro

I have a metro app which has a grid that contains a row of rectangle objects, I would like to animate all the rectangles at the same time (scale from 0 to 1 in 1 second). I would like to use Resources as much as possible and avoid code duplication. The basic skeleton of the Grid is Below.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Rectangle" x:Key="RectangleStyle">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
            <Setter Property="RadiusX" Value="10"/>
            <Setter Property="RadiusY" Value="10"/>
            <Setter Property="RadiusY" Value="10"/>
            <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                        <ScaleTransform x:Name="RectangleScaleTransform"  ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.Triggers>
       <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Rectangle.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RectangleScaleTransform"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)" From="0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:1"  />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Rectangle.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RectangleScaleTransform"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)" From="0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:1"  />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Grid.Triggers>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource RectangleStyle}" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource RectangleStyle}" />
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource RectangleStyle}"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource RectangleStyle}"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Style="{StaticResource RectangleStyle}"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" Style="{StaticResource RectangleStyle}"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="6" Style="{StaticResource RectangleStyle}"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="Red" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="7" Style="{StaticResource RectangleStyle}"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I dont want to have to add `RenderTransform` to each Individual Rectangle and I dont want to add a trigger to each Rectangle Triangle either as that seems to be a lot of duplication. With the code above I am getting a `Cannot resolve TargetName "RectangleScaleTransform` error.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can refer to named elements defined in a style like that.

Perhaps you could use code-behind?

Haven't tried this, but just off the top of my head, you could do this:

1. Name all your rectangles in XAML
2. In the .xaml.cs after the InitializeComponent call, put all the rectangles in a list, and loop through each to add a render transform programmatically.
3. Then when you need to start the animation, animate the render transforms for all the rectangles in the list

Comment: The style does actually style all the rectangles, I could use code behind but I was hoping to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Sure - the style works. I think you can't refer to elements inside a style by name (like you did in the Storyboard) though.